# Redirecting internal php files to 403 error page

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

In my webpage, i am using several php files and using calling them by ajax. Like in page `abc.html` there is a ajax call to `example.php` which takes some input by post, calculate something out of them and return a value to `ajax success` function. I want to implement a method in which if user want to access `example.php` directly by `http://somesite.com/example.php` it should redirect it to other page like error page or index page without not manipulating the response to original ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go inside your PHP file and modify to be something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['your_post_variable'])){ 
            header("Location: index.php"); // or whatever page you like
            exit();
        }
        else{ /* your code for when $_POST is submitted via ajax request */ 

        }
```

If anyone goes on the file directly, their $_POST will be empty, and they would be redirected to the location.

You should use `!empty` instead of `isset`. `isset` return true for $_POST because $_POST array is superglobal and always exists (set).

A better method would also be to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`.

All the best.

Comment: what $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] will return if i am directly calling it?

Comment: The REQUEST_METHOD meta-variable MUST be set to the method which should be used by the script to process the request, as described in section 4.3. It will return if POST or GET is being used. I would actually stick with using !empty. It's your best option.